# How to have a multiple select field in django in the form of a drop down box

Tags: python, django, forms

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am a newbie in django.

```
class studentRegister(forms.Form):
courseList = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Courses.objects.all())
```

Thank you and appreciate your time, I just want to modify this type of form so I can multiple select two or more options at a time and that returns in a list maybe?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is work with Bootstrap classes and Python.

**forms.py**

```
class yourForm(forms.Form):
options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=[(option, option) for option in
             Options.objects.all()], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    label="myLabel", required=True, error_messages={'required': 'myRequiredMessage'})
```

**view.py**

```
def anything(...):
    (...)
    form = yourForm( )
    (...)
    return render(request, "myPage.html", {'form': form})
```

**myPage.html**

```
(...)
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="col-md-12 dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ field.label_tag }}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div><a href="#">{{ field }}</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `SelectMultiple` widget. [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple)

```
class studentRegister(forms.Form):
    courseList = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Courses.objects.all(), widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
```

If this does not fit your needs, you can try using this [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/747/).

Comment: Sorry this question may be dumb but how do I use this snipped do I have to put it in a certain location

Comment: You can create a widgets.py file. Import it in your forms.py and use it like the code above.

Comment: Oh, I think the widget is a bit outdated. Edit the widgets.py and replace `newforms` with `forms.`.