# Django - dropdown form with multiple select

Tags: python, django, forms

**I need guidance building a django *dropdown* `forms.Form` field in which I can select *multiple* choices.  I need to select multiple locations on the `office` field of the form.**

When submitted, the form needs to return a `list` of the chosen offices (e.g. `["New York", "Los Angeles"]` or `["Austin"]`).  Returning a `tuple` is also acceptable.

---

The best I can do right now is build a [multipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) for `office` with the following:

```
from django import forms

class my_Form(forms.Form):

    OPTIONS = [
        ("0", "*ALL"),
        ("1", "New York"),
        ("2", "Los Angeles"),
        ]

    office = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=OPTIONS,
            initial='0',
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
            required=True,
            label='Office',
        )
```

resulting in this form field layout:

[image]

---

However, I would like this field to be a dropdown, to take up less space on the page.

I found this [djangosnippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/747/) but (1) a few people have mentioned it appears out of date (I can't confirm), and (2) I first want to check if a built-in django form/widget setup can fulfill this task before using custom code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Dropdown" boxes don't support multiple selection in HTML; browsers will always render it as a flat box as your image shows.

You probably want to use some kind of JS widget - [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) is a popular one. There are a couple of Django projects - [django-select2](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-select2), [django-easy-select](https://github.com/asyncee/django-easy-select2) - that aim to make it simple to integrate that into your form; I have no experience with either of them.

(And yes, that snippet - like many things on Djangosnippets - is massively out of date; "newforms" was renamed to "forms" even before version 1.0 of Django.)

Answer (score 4):

You can choose multiple choices by using Django select2. Include below code in your respective HTML file.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select_field_class" multiple="multiple" name="option" id="option">
      <option value="">Enter the option</option>
      {% for option in options %}
         <option value="{{ option.id }}">{{ option.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
</select>

$('.select_field_class').select2( { placeholder: "Select here", maximumSelectionSize: 100  } );
```

Comment: How can I add the 'selected' attribute based on the choice

Comment: "$('.select_field_class').select2( { placeholder: "Select here", maximumSelectionSize: 100  } );" - where does this go? Doesn't look right just floating there, and doesn't work on my implementation when I copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

This is late but hope it helps someone else.

You can also do it a combination of `django forms` and a select2 widget `Select2MultipleWidget` to make it look cleaner.

```
class YourCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
     CHOICES = (("address1","address1"), ("address2","address2"))
     address=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget=Select2MultipleWidget)

     class Meta:
         model = YourModel
         fields = ("field1","address",)
```

Do not forget to install and import the django select2 widgets

Comment: NameError: name 'Select2MultipleWidget' is not defined. I am getting this error. I have installed "django-select2" and tried to implement your solution. Can you please help me out where am i doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Singh -- Have you imported the widget itself?

`from django_select2.forms import Select2MultipleWidget`

Comment: yes, @codebender. I implemented Multiselect checkbox and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I said [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259484/how-to-have-a-multiple-select-field-in-django-in-the-form-of-a-drop-down-box/42701032#42701032), one suggestion is use Bootstrap with Python.

**forms.py**

```
(...)
class yourForm(forms.Form):
    options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=OPTIONS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    label="myLabel", required=True, error_messages={'required': 'myRequiredMessage'})
```

**view.py**

```
def anything(...):
    (...)
    form = yourForm( )
    (...)
    return render(request, "myPage.html", {'form': form})
```

**myPage.html**

```
(...)
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="col-md-12 dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ field.label_tag }}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div><a href="#">{{ field }}</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
(...)
```

Comment: Doesnt this invalidate Djangos form validation for anyone else? Will be helpful if it doesnt for anyone else, then i know i have something wrong with my code!