# Checkbox in Dropdown Django

Tags: python, django, dropdown

I have a form in my django app and it contains a dropdown.

**Models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    mtypes = (('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'), ('D', 'D'), ('E', 'E'))
    material_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0, choices=mtypes)
```

**Views.py**

```
class QuizCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Quiz
    fields = ('material_type')
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/quiz_add_form.html'

    def form_valid (self, form):
        quiz = form.save(commit=False)
        quiz.owner = self.request.user
        quiz.save()
        return redirect('teachers:quiz_change', quiz.pk)
```

**html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'teachers:quiz_change_list' %}">RFQs</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Post New RFQ</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <h2 class="mb-3">Post New RFQ</h2>


        {% csrf_token %}
        {#<h3>Material Details</h3>#}
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
                {{ form.material_type|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

I am able to display material_type as a dropdown list but can I add checkboxes to this DropDown?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573772/django-dropdown-form-with-multiple-select/39573931#39573931) is what the closest I could find but the documentation on the listed libraries is not so clear. 
How do I do that?

What I have:

[image]

what I want:

checkboxes against A,B,C..

Comment: Can you put a picture of how you're getting?

Comment: By check boxes you mean radio buttons? Since it's a choice field, you can't save more than one option.

Comment: @JoãoVictorMonte Yes, I mean Radiobuttons. How can I alter the code such that I can save more than 1 option?

Comment: You need to create a new model with 2 fields. 1 manytomany referencing to this model and other with mtypes = (('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'), ('D', 'D'), ('E', 'E')) and  material_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0, choices=mtypes)

Comment: If I have time later I code it and post as answer

Comment: @JoãoVictorMonte Sure

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/), or just create a widget

[image]

Comment: I want a multiselectfield in a dropdown, I know how to do what you did.