# Django - How to make multiple choice field in Admin Field?

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I have the following Django model:

```
class Level(models.Model):
        
        topics = # need to put option choice field here
        shortDescription = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

I want my admins to be able to go into my application and for the **topics**, I want them to be select multiple values from a list in a user friendly way (dropdown)

How can I make is so that admins using my app can go in and choose from a list of topics? They need to be able to choose multiple but they can select 1 if they choose to.

Comment: The keyword is `MultipleChoiceField` .. It might not render the field how you like it (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplechoicefield-django-forms/) .. but there are some js addons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573772/django-dropdown-form-with-multiple-select , but you might have to make a custom admin form to use them